# No sound in ubuntu

Tags: sound

to start I know there are a million topics on this but I can't seem to get this to work. In short, I've done most of everything that I've found and have the same problem as this guy: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=159605

This is the only thing I haven't done it seems but there is no pulse folder in .config/ even after reinstalling pulseaudio. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**After searching, I have found a simple answer. Just execute**

```
killall pulseaudio
```

Your speakers should work fine now. To ensure this, test the sound stack in System Settings > Sound > Test Sound (Speaker test, Not Digital Output (S/PDIF) test)

**If killall pulseaudio wasn't working .**

Run

```
gpasswd -a yourusername audio

Then do

killall pulseaudio
```

**Sometimes the problem is that alsa somehow got muted. Open a terminal and type:**

```
alsamixer
```

and disable Auto-Mute Mode. The mute can be toggled with the M key.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, first step didn't work, after doing gpasswd -a calhix audio, it said "adding user calhix to group audio," Did the killall pulseaudio command and still nothing. Went to alsamixer and it is set as 00. For some reason though, after doing the sudo gpasswd -a calhix audio command and then killall pulseaudio and testing and it not working, i tried doing pulseaudio -k and it didn't bring up the error message "[pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process." I cannot replicate this again though (if that helps at all).

Comment: also I have just noticed that the .pulse folder is in the /home/user/ folder, not in config folder

Comment: when plugging headphones in, i hear a slight hiss for a few seconds then it goes away. when playing youtube videos it only buffers and won't play and I hear a hiss while it buffers. audacious just stays at the beginning of a song and doesn't even move, it's just always at 0:00 and for some reason stays muted, even after putting the volume up on the program, it just mutes itself

Comment: This can be closed as I just reinstalled ubuntu since i've been dealing with this for too long and gave up trying. It's working now that pulseaudio hasn't been installed and i'm sure ill never reinstall it ever.